# Bootstrap 3 Horizontal Nav adding anchor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

Getting some off behaviour with my Bootstrap horizontal navigation, for some reason it seems to be adding an extra anchor link into the first `<li><!-- here --></li>` element.

Code:

```
<li class='submenu'>
<a href='#'>
     <img src='{{ URL::asset('img/menu/performance.png') }}' /> Performance
         <ul class='nav'>
    <li><a href='#'>abc</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>abc</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>abc</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>abc</a></li>
     </ul>
</a>                    
</li>
```

What Chromes Inspector says:

```
<li class="submenu">
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://xxxxxx/img/menu/performance.png"> Performance

    </a>
    <ul class="nav" style="display: block;"><a href="#">
        </a><li><a href="#"></a><a ref="#">abc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Any one got an idea's of why this is happening? I hacky fixed it with the following CSS:

```
.left-nav .submenu li:nth-child(2) > a:first-child {
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: You have links inside a link. That's wrong!!!

Comment: You have your entire unordered list inside an anchor tag. Why?

Comment: Yep, got it guys. I moved them outside of the anchor and its now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using links within links, causing this to happen. I have moved the secondary `<ul>` outside of the anchor tab and its now working.

Answer (score 4):

You should not have any links inside another link.
This is not valid HTML.

If the browser encounters a link tag while already inside a link tag it will add
the closing tag for the first link.